# Return item on complex condition at Enum.each

Tags: elixir

I have this collection

```
collection = [%{"id" => 1, "items" => ["test1", "test2"]},
              %{"id" => 2, "items" => ["test3", "test4"]}]
```

How having the item `"test3"` can I obtain the map `%{"id" => 2, "items" => ["test3", "test4"]}]` ?

How could it be done functional style? and return `nil` if not found?

```
Enum.each(collection, fn(element) ->
  if Enum.member?(element["items"], "test3") do
    # return the value?
  end
end)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Enum.find/2`:

```
Enum.find(collection, fn x -> "test3" in x["items"] end)
```

```
iex(1)> collection = [%{"id" => 1, "items" => ["test1", "test2"]},
...(1)>               %{"id" => 2, "items" => ["test3", "test4"]}]
iex(2)> Enum.find(collection, fn x -> "test3" in x["items"] end)
%{"id" => 2, "items" => ["test3", "test4"]}
iex(3)> Enum.find(collection, fn x -> "test5" in x["items"] end)
nil
```

Answer (score 0):

While [`Enum.find/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#find/3) is a perfectly legit way to achieve the goal, the [arguably] more idiomatic approach would be to use the plain old good comprehension:

```rb
for %{"items" => items} = elem <- collection,
    "test3" in items, do: elem
#⇒ [%{"id" => 2, "items" => ["test3", "test4"]}]
```

The above returns the list, that might be then e. g. piped to [`List.first/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html#first/1) to retrieve the first found element. In general, the idea to pick up the first matched element out from a list that even is not guaranteed to be sorted sounds risky to me.

Comment: When I try this(.exs file, elixir 1.8.1) it doesn't return a list but the same result as the accepted answer.

Comment: update: returns a list during a `mix test`. For some reason in a .exs file it does not return a list.

Comment: @maz comprehension _always_ returns a list.

Comment: yeah for some reason it works now. I must have been doing something wrong. ignore my previous comments.